Proof of homeomorphism of quotients of $n$-skeleton of $\Delta$-complex
Given a $\Delta$-complex ($X$, $\Sigma = (\Sigma_p)_{p \in \mathbb{N}}$), we can consider the evaluation map $ev \colon \Sigma_n \times \Delta^n \to X^n$ by
$(\sigma,t) \mapsto \sigma(t)$ where $X^n$ is the $n$-skeleton
$$ X^n = \cup_{p \leq n} \cup_{\sigma \in \Sigma_p} \sigma(\Delta^p) $$.
We give each $\Sigma_p$ the discrete topolgoy so that the evaluation map becomes continuous.
We then are supposed to get a homeomorphism of quotients
$$ Y:= \frac{\Sigma_n \times \Delta^n}{\Sigma_n \times \partial \Delta^n} 
\stackrel{ev}{\to} \frac{X^n}{X^{n-1}}$$.
I wanted to do this by showing that $ev$ is closed, but I'm not sure if the details work out. Here it is:
Let $A \subset Y$ be closed and let $Z = \Sigma_n \times \partial \Delta^n$ and
$\overline{Z} = \pi (Z)$ in the quotient. If $\overline{Z} \in A$ then $\pi^{-1}(Y-A)
\subset \Sigma_n \times (\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n)$ is open and $ev$ is injective on here. I claim $ev$ is a local homeomorphism on $\Sigma_n \times (\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n)$: let $(\sigma, t) \in \Sigma_n \times (\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n)$. Then
we can find some open neighborhood $U$ of $t$ contained in $\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n$ and since $\sigma$ is injective on $U$ and the subsets $\tau (\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n)$ are disjoint for $\tau$ ranging over $\Sigma_n$, we have that $U = \sigma^{-1} (\sigma(U))$, hence $\sigma(U)$ is open in $X^n - X^{n-1}$, thus also saturated with respect to the quotient, hence also open in the quotient space. Bijective local homeomorphisms are homeomorphisms, so $ev$ restricted to
$\Sigma_n \times (\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n)$ is an embedding, so $\frac{X^n}{X^{n-1}} - ev(A) = ev (\pi^{-1}(Y-A))$ is open, hence $A$ is closed.
In the case where $\overline{Z} \not \subset A$, we have $\pi^{-1}(A) \subset \Sigma_n \times (\Delta^n - \partial \Delta^n)$ is closed, so by the above, its image under $ev$ is closed.
